# Magento sending wrong Payment Info block in e-mail template

Tags: magento-1.4, magento

Im experiencing a problem with a Payment module (librepag) witch follows:

The module has 2 template "info blocks" (that block with the payment details):

1. used on the backend (app/design/**adminhtml**/base/default/template/librepag/info/cartao.phtml) - it has some action buttons that the customer shouldn't see
2. used on the e-mail template (app/design/**frontend**/base/default/template/librepag/info/cartao.phtml)

When the customer make an order, the correct template (#2) is sent. But when we are at backend order view and click on **Send Email** button, the #1 is sent instead.

I noticed that in the module Model has the

```
protected $_formBlockType = 'librepag/form_cartao';
protected $_infoBlockType = 'librepag/info_cartao';
```

witch corresponds to this particular block

```
class Weblibre_Librepag_Block_Info_Cartao extends Mage_Payment_Block_Info_Ccsave
{
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('librepag/info/cartao.phtml');
}
...
```

**Why the system is sending different info blocks for the same sendNewOrderEmail method?**
I saw a [**similar thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875784/editing-magento-sales-e-mail-payment-block), but didn't figured out how to simply specify another info block on email templates on this module.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're in the backend an choose the send mail function the area of every action is `admin` not `frontend`, as it's in the shop frontend.

That's why the relative path `librepag/info/cartao.phtml` is interpreted as `adminhtml/default/default/librepag/info/cartao.phtml`

To solve this you can call `$this->setArea('frontend');` before `setTemplate()` in the constructor.

Comment: I solved in a more complex way, by adding a beforeToHtml() method on the block with $this->addData(array(
            'show_buttons' => (bool)($this->getRequest()->getRequestedActionName() != 'email')
            )); And making a if($this->getShowButtons()) at phtml file. I guess your way is very better. Thank you.